# Elasticsearch : which type has more relevancy? Boosting? Mapping or?

Tags: elasticsearch

In my Elasticsearch index, I have types like this:

```
a: {value:'xx cc',type:'city'}
b: {value:'xx dd',type:'school'}
c: {value:'xx',type:'school'}...
```

When I search `value='xx'`, I hope the '`city`' can be shown first, not '`school`', how can I achieve this?

Comment: You should try with boosting. You can do it in two ways. At index-time and at query-time. What you need depends on what you want to achieve. I believe your example is simplified so I can't make any suggestion here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the boolean query:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match": {
                    "value": { 
                        "query":    "xx",
                        "operator": "and"
                    }
                }
            },
            "should": [ 
                { "match": { "type": "city" }}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The more clauses match the document, the most relevant it will be. Results with 'city' will consequently have a better score.

Comment: @lac Great! Don't forget to accept the answer to show that the question has been solved. ;)